# Understanding this English to Japanese translation

Tags: translation, particles, english-to-japanese, parsing

In this sentence:

> 俺のような人が、アナタの目の前から、奪っていくこともあるけどな

I don't understand this part 奪っていくこともあるけどな. It's a translation of :

> Someone like me swoops in and takes it from you

How can I parse this part? if it's:

> 奪っていく こと　も　ある　けど　な

Why are も and けど used in this sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you got it from [this paragraph](http://wwefan.com/g126/):

> エリートがいないと、レスリングはつまらない。あと、お前らに言いたいことがある。今日みたいな日は、人生に1度しかない。俺を信じて、夢を叶えて、高い目標を狙うことを恐れないで。**しかし、夢を叶えそうになる時、俺のような人が、アナタの目の前から、奪っていくこともあるけどな。** なぜなら、俺が1番。俺は1番才能がある。

One point of advice is to provide the entire sentence and not just a fragment. It makes much more sense that way.

Translation:

> However, just when your dream is about to come true, someone like me
>   might also take it away from you right in front of your face.

The key in this sentence is the `こともある` and `けどな` parts.

> こともある

Here it is similar to the grammar form [ことがある](http://j-nihongo.com/dic-kotogaaru/) but using `も` to imply "also".

So 奪っていくこともある is saying "(I) may also take it from you".

> けどな

けどな can be broken down further into けど and な. けど is used here to make it less direct and avoid making a firm assertion. な just puts more feeling into it.

Comment: Does けど add the "may" in "may also take it from you"?

Comment: @Jon It only say "though" or "however". Yes it makes pleonasm with しかし, but しかし is rather the one grammatical redundant here.